# Should the intentional absence of a value rather be represented by value-convention or through explicit flag?

Tags: database-design, user-experience

Following context:

in a set of metadata that contains a lot of possible fields there exists at least one field (possibly more in the future) that can be empty by intention but realistically will be relatively rarely and in most cases the field being empty represents a mistake/carelessness of an employee.

Due to that fact, PO and ontology-designer wish for the user to make an explicit statement if leaving out the value was intentional, for example by a checkbox that basically communicates "I know what I am doing. This data actually doesn't exist in this case and there are valid logical reasons for it to not exist.".

I wonder what would be the best way to handle this on the database-side.

Would I rather define a const-value to be inserted into that column that represents this intentional absence or should I define a seperate column that just contains a flag to show intentional absence?

My thoughts so far:
I am not sure as I don't know how many of these cases might come up in the future which might lead to the respective table becoming more and more polluted with such flags as the model is still in vivid active development.
On the other hand side just representing it by "encoding" the case as special value makes room for a user to enter this value by hand even if I choose some obscure value which would possibly lead to erroneous data getting into the DB. One could argue that this case is incredibly unlikely due to the nature of the set of users touching the product but it is still a possibility.
Theoretically I could catch that case by form-data-validation before writing to the DB but that seems overly complicated.

Comment: It's not a special flag; it's just a *required field.*  Fields are made *required* for the very reasons you state; to make the entry by the user *deliberate and explicit.*  If you need something to be explicitly empty, provide a "none" option.

Comment: Hm...kinda makes sense if you put it like that. I gotta admit that conceptually the whole thing felt a bit counter-intuitive to me in the first place. It is a pattern I associate with destructive operations ("you really want to delete that?" "you really want to quit?"...). I can't remember ever seeing a form where I had to check a box to say "Yep, I'm leaving that out. No worries."

Comment: @Wolfone You sometimes have fields marked "N/A" or "Not applicable". For example number of cylinders on an electric car makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The situation where a field is not blank, but has a special value that means "this field has intentionally been left blank", is sometimes called an "in-band null".

It has similar problems to real null values, except it can propagate more easily through the system. This is where you get people's addresses being set to [Null Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Island), the ["NULL" license plate](https://www.wired.com/story/null-license-plate-landed-one-hacker-ticket-hell/), etc.

Having a separate flag indicating that the other value is definitely not valid can help avoid that problem - but only if you remember to check the flag. It may be worth thinking not only about the database but how you want to represent it in DTOs and API values as an absence-of-value.

Comment: Valuable input! Thanks for that! I think I can work from your answer and the comment on the question. Also good point about representation in other contexts.